# How to add image to table cell and read the image's url value from database field in ssrs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, image, url, reporting-services

I am working on a ssrs report. I have a table and it is linked to a database query.

Query returns a field which includes image urls of every item.

For example:

```
ID  Name    URL
1   Line1   https://www.servername.com/images/a.jpg
2   Line2   https://www.servername.com/images/b.jpg
```

Then i add an image from toolbox to table's last cell. Then from Image Properties, i choose database, then i choose database field and MIME type then i click OK.

After i run the report, i see crosses instead of image. Why is it happening? How can i show the images properly?

#### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

when you set the source to database you are saying that the image is stored in the database.  What you actually have stored is a link, so you need to use image source external and add the data field to the expression for the "use this image".

Comment: image url is a data field like "https://..." and i want to use that url in the field to show image. i tried to add with external image option but it failed again.

Answer (score 0):

Select External - then in the dropdown for the "Use this Image" select the data field that has the url in it.

At run time it will pull the url from the database and show the image.

Regards,